# Why can't I convert noOfChildren to Integer?

Tags: swift

I am trying to calculate the number of cookies for each child.
It gives an error:

> error: value of optional type 'Int?' not unwrapped;  did you mean to
>   use '!' or '?'?

```
let noOfCookies = 50
var noOfChildren : String = "5"
let typeOfCookies = "Oreo"

print("\(typeOfCookies) can be split among \(noOfChildren) 
and each gets \(noOfCookies/Int(noOfChildren))")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Int(noOfChildren)` tries to take your String and convert it to an int, returning an *optional Int*, or `Int?`. If, for instance, `noOfChildren` was "fish" instead of "5", `Int(noOfChildren)` would return `nil`, because it can't be converted. That's why you have an optional `Int?`. You can handle unwrapping an optional in a few ways:

- Force unwrap it: `let myInt = Int(noOfChildren)!`. This will get rid of the optional right away, but again, if `noOfChildren` was "fish", your app will crash, because it can't force unwrap.
- Nil coalesce it: `let myInt = Int(noOfChildren) ?? 0`. This will try to unwrap it, and if we get `nil`, it defaults to the second value (0).
- Use an if-statement to check if it exists: `if let myInt = Int(noOfChildren) { ... }`. Do the print, or whatever else you want, inside, where `myInt` will be a non-optional.

You will want to read up about optionals if you want to continue with Swift; they're a major topic.

Comment: Thank you. As I am using division here, I can't use 0, Instead, I am using 
`let myInt = Int(noOfChildren) ?? 1`

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that because `Int(String)` returns an `Int?` type. You can't perform math with an optional type. Try this:

```
let noOfCookies = 50
var noOfChildren : String = "5"
let typeOfCookies = "Oreo"

if let numChildren = Int(noOfChildren) {
    print("\(typeOfCookies) can be split among \(noOfChildren) and each gets \(noOfCookies/numChildren)")
} else {
    // Handle inability to convert String to Int
}
```

I like @ConnorNeville's explanation in his answer. I think this is the best approach of the three he listed because you will want to know if / when you can't perform the conversion from String to Int